# Rmi Client cant find Server stub

Tags: java, rmi

I have a server project and a client inside it . Server runs fine . Client inside server project runs fine too . But when i create another Client project ,with the interface inside but not the server ofc, i compile it and when i try to run it i get this error . i have read a lot of stuff but nothing works yet, i tried security manager to client , i tried a lot of thinks actually and i keep getting this error, I read also that i need to start a new rmi registry for clients project i tried that to but i can't open a new one 
error:

run:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RMIServer03_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)
    at Client.<init>(Client.java:65)
    at Client.main(Client.java:141)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RMIServer03_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:396)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:186)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:264)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:219)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    ... 4 more
C:\Users\blue-icon\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to to is generate the stub clas with `rmic` and deploy it to the client.

This is mentioned in every worthwhile RMI tutorial. Rather surprising that you didn't encounter it.

Comment: i used to be able to run external clients on the past but i format my pc and after that i made the excact same steps in order to be able to run rmi but now when i try to run external clients (ss. without the servers class inside the project ) i get this error....

Comment: If you did it and it doesn't work, you didn't do it properly. It works for everyone else.

Comment: I've been using RMI and advising people on it for twenty years. It is you who has not understood my answer. You have to deploy the stub class to the client's CLASSPATH. This is mentioned in every RMI tutorial I have ever seen, starting with [Oracle's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html).